# A bound for a holomorphic function in the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic function in the unit circle $B(0,1)$ and $f(B(0,1))\subseteq B(0,1)$. Prove that $$\left| f(z)-\frac{f(0)(1-|z|^2)}{1-|f(0)|^2|z|^2} \right| \leq \frac{|z|(1-|f(0)|^2)}{1-|f(0)|^2|z|^2}$$ I know that I probably need to construct another holomorphic function and use the [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) or the [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), but I don't know how.